# ESP32 shorting booting time

Tags: esp32

My system needs to be in deep sleep mode and wake up every second, how can I predict and make the boot time as short as possible? I'm a bit surprised by the poor performance of ESP32's low power mode, 150 uA deep sleep, and then a forced reboot sounds crazy to me, am I missing something?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I speed it up from 297ms to 47ms.

Form menu config:

Bootloader log verbosity:
No output. Improve 100ms

Default log verbosity.
No output. improves 110ms

Skip image validation when exiting deep sleep.
Yes. Improve 40ms

In theory, It can be as fast as 20ms something else to improve?

Comment: Do you mean `47ms`?

Comment: @Cully yes, I just edited the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Waking up takes around 200-300 ms (in my projects, switched of bootmessages). And then you have to execute initializing ánd executing code.. doesn’t make sense per second if power is an issue. The ESP has a lot of advantages, but it’s power hungry compared to a pic microcontroller.

In one of my projects the esp wakes up, initiates a i2c request to a sensor. Has to wait 5s and process. I investigated if sleeping for the 5s was better for powerusage, but it wasn’t. Slowing down processor speed is more effective for those moments, but still in the mA range.